sklearn LeaveOneOut with cross_validate/GridSearchCV: how can I use confusion matrix-based scores as the custom scoring functions?
I’m using LeaveOneOut from sklearn, along with GridSesrchCV and cross_validate. I’m working on a medical problem so I’m interested in finding sensitivity and specificity.
However, because LeaveOneOut only evaluates the model on a single sample, sensitivity and specificity make no sense on each individual cross validation run. I basically always get division by zero errors when trying.
Sensitivity and specificity only make sense when I aggregate all of the scores produced through one entire LeaveOneOut cross validation run, which is what I’d like to do with GridSearchCV. Instead of just having 0 and 1 scores for each LOO fold, I’d like to have one score (probably F1) for the entire LOO run.
How can I pass a custom scorer to GridSearchCV and cross_validate to do this?
I’ve tried using make_scorer on a “sensitivity_score” function that uses confusion_matrix. However, this doesn’t work because each LOO fold has one 1 sample in y_true and y_pred, so the confusion matrix is 1x1 and the concepts of sensitivity, specificity, and F1 make no sense.
